# Show div when variable (time) is 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to show div when time (importing from database) - current time will be 0. How to do that? Here's the code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='alert' id='" . $row['id'] . "' style='display:none'><br><br><center><h2>";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $row['category'];
    echo "</h2><br><br><hr><br><br></center>";
    echo $row['description'];
    echo "</div>";
    $timeFirst  = strtotime($row['date']);
    $timeSecond = strtotime("now");
    $differenceInSeconds = $timeFirst - $timeSecond;
    if ($differenceInSeconds==0)
    {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
        echo "$('#". $row['id'] . "').show();";
        echo "$('#". $row['id'] . "').delay(15000);";
        echo "$('#". $row['id'] . "').hide();";
        echo "});";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$differenceInSeconds = $timeFirst - time();`

Comment: but i think you never see this div :)

Comment: div looks normally without display:none etc.

Comment: I just think that fall in interval of one second rather difficult

Comment: There is delay 15 seconds :)

Comment: your if statement have to work in that interval.Maybe you make less strong condition. Something like `abs($differenceInSeconds0)  < 5`

Comment: Is your time from database in the future ? Because if it's not `$timeFirst - $timeSecond` will likely always be negative and nothing will be written in your `if ($differenceInSeconds==0)` block.

Comment: Yes, in database time is in feature. After change to $timeFirst - time() still don't work

Comment: What format is your database date in ? Unix timestamp ?

Comment: timestamp, input also have datetime-local type. In $timeFirst format is changing

Comment: echo `$timeFirst . " ". $timeSecond;` before. Are they equal?

Comment: I have echo $differenceInSeconds and it's 0 at time

Comment: @OP please don't delete your post content once it is answered.

Comment: Can you also help me with one thing? Can jquery refreshing page every 5 minutes but if div is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add a `setTimeout()` to your javascript code instead of `if ($differenceInSeconds==0) {}` PHP side.

Also you need to rewrite your jQuery from (effectively showing an element, delaying nothing and hiding it right away)

```
$("#element").show();
$("#element").delay(15000);
$("#element").hide();
```

to

```
$("#element").show().delay(15000).hide(0);
```

Full code below.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='alert' id='" . $row['id'] . "' style='display:none'><br><br><center><h2>";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $row['category'];
    echo "</h2><br><br><hr><br><br></center>";
    echo $row['description'];
    echo "</div>";
    $timeFirst  = strtotime($row['date']);
    $timeSecond = strtotime("now");
    $differenceInSeconds = $timeFirst - $timeSecond;

    // Adding a setTimeout so your JS code actually gets written and executes when it should.
    if ($differenceInSeconds >= 0) {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
        echo "window.setTimeout(function() {";
        echo "$('#". $row['id'] . "').show().delay(15000).hide(0);";
        echo "}, " . $differenceInSeconds * 1000 . ");";
        echo "});";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try now ? Can you actually compare with content that should be displayed ? Is there any javascript error (I don't think so) ? Can you post your HTML source to pastebin or something ? I think it needs inspection.

Comment: No I need to see your generated **HTML** source code, not server-side code. Just press `ctrl-U` and paste it somewhere :-)

Comment: OK I found the problem. You wrote your `show()` `delay()` `hide()` sequence the wrong way - effectively hiding your element just after displaying them. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Oh wow! It's working! Thank you. But there is another problem. When time is 0 then $differenceInSeconds is -1, -2 etc. and div is showing alltime when time is -

Comment: OK let me update. Do you mean alerts with a date in the past ?

Comment: Yeah, alerts are showing still when time is in the past

Answer (score 0):

Try it :-

```
<?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div class='alert' id='" . $row['id'] . "' style='display:none'><br><br><center><h2>";
        echo $row['title'];
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $row['category'];
        echo "</h2><br><br><hr><br><br></center>";
        echo $row['description'];
        echo "</div>";
        $timeFirst  = strtotime($row['date']);
        $timeSecond = strtotime("now");
        $differenceInSeconds = $timeFirst - $timeSecond;

        if ($differenceInSeconds==0)
        { ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#<?php echo $row['id'] ?>').show();
                    $('#<?php echo $row['id'] ?>').delay(15000);
                    $('#<?php echo $row['id'] ?>').hide();
                });
            </script>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should provide some details what you have done in this answer instead of just `Try it`.